# Unity nothing happens when a object collides

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I want to log in console when a cube passes through an another cube, the another cube has mesh collider with Convex and isTrigger is set to true.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class score_addations : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[SerializeField]
    //private int SCORE = 0;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "score")
        {
            Debug.Log("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Fail");
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        //Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Here is an image of my game [image]

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` will not work for Triggers. Try using `OnTriggerEnter`.

Comment: Let me try `OnTriggerEnter`

Comment: Script error: OnTriggerEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collider
The message will be ignored.

Comment: Please see [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

Comment: Show me the code which relates to me.

Comment: I've sent you a documentation page which explains how OnTriggerEnter works. There is also an example usage below.

Comment: Hey, I forgot to say that my Cube is moving by an animation does Triggers work with animations??

Answer (score 1):

for triggers you use `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)` Use this code

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "score")
    {
        Debug.Log("Pass");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it works on animations because my cube is moving by an animation.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: @RTX_CODE probably not .. physics and collision detection does not work correctly if your objects are not moved by the `Rigidbody` -> Physics engine. If you move an object by animation you might brake the system.